# How to hide Facebook register/login message?

Tags: facebook, firefox, login, browser-addons

I don't have a Facebook account and I don't want any.

The problem is many companies use their public Facebook pages as their websites these days, especially pubs, small shops etc.

When I enter their Facebook pages, this extremely annoying message appears:

[image]

I click "Not now", which makes this message a little smaller, but it still covers about 20% of the page. I hate it.

**How can I get rid of this once for all?**

Comment: We need a maintained plugin? Or, at least in July 2018, this solution still works: Adding the text @-moz-document domain(www.facebook.com){div[class="_5hn6"]{display:none!important;}} to userChrome.css, see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125308

Comment: @ArnoTeigseth Can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the tag that create this frame by *Inspect Element*.

1. Press F12 or click on the right button of your mouse and select *Inspect Element*.
2. Click on the left top icon:

[image]

3. Select the frame to delete:

[image]

4. Press the delete key.
5. Be happy.

Comment: I am happy, thanks! And I managed to get even one step farther: with [this Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hideelement/) I can remove the tag you pointed to with just one click!

Answer (score 1):

At least in July 2018, this solution still works:
Adding the text

```
@-moz-document domain(facebook.com){div[class="_5hn6"]{display:none!important;}}
```

to **userContent.css**

See also [support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125308](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125308) but note, it's userContent.css not userChrome.css

In short:

- Firefox menu Help > Troubleshooting Information > Profile Directory:
- Open the directory with the button there
- create or open the folder called "chrome"
- create a file called **userContent.css** in the chrome directory, with the contents above. (*Beware that if you use notepad for this, it could add a .txt extension, messing up everything. Alternatively, download [this file](http://www.teigseth.no/files/userContent.css) and save it to the chrome directory*)
- restart Firefox

This will work until Facebook decides to change their approach. Or some judge decides it is illegal to show that kind of popups.

Comment: This is a great solution, because it is permanent.I would upvote twice if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you want to hear but - register for Facebook.

Go to security settings and make everything totally private.   Don't invite  anyone to be your friend.   Decline any friend requests you get.    After that don't go into Facebook at all - except when you want to check the page for a specific place.

Either that, or choose not to spend your money with any businesses that use Facebook as their webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that seems to work elegantly -- in that it doesn't require creating or editing any configuration files -- at present for Chrome in August 2020.  It may be possible to do the same in Firefox and other browsers, but I haven't explored that.

- Install the Chrome extension [Live editor for CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-editor-for-css-less/ifhikkcafabcgolfjegfcgloomalapol?hl=en)
- From any Facebook page where the banner appears, press Alt-Shift-C to display the CSS editing window
- In the CSS editing window, paste the following line of code

> ._5hn6 {visibility: hidden}

- The banner should disappear immediately
- Once the banner disappears, it is fine to close the CSS editing window
- Also, to make the change permanent -- i.e., so that the banner is always suppressed when visiting any Facebook page later on -- click the pin icon (second from left after plus icon) before closing the CSS editing window

Credit is due to:

- Arno Teigseth for identifying the offending CSS element that displays the Facebook banner
- Karl Hodge for providing [a similar method to suppress unwanted elements in Google Street View](https://medium.com/@karlhodge/take-better-google-street-view-screenshots-e8b025861756), which inspired this solution for Facebook